# Simple iOS POST http request

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

I am looking to make POST http request to a PHP file from an iOS app. I just need to take the value in a field and post it to the PHP. The android version isn't completed but it is at least working and here is the code:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check In Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void postData(String phone) {
        String content = "";
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("MY_URL_HERE");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", phone));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // Custom code for response
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            // Check the HTTP resquest for success
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // toast here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check in Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_FORBIDDEN) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // toast here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Number already checked in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            } else if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST); {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // toast here
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone number not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:ClientProtocolException " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("ALFA", "HTTPReq:IOException " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Nothing too fancy, I am just having the hardest time finding how to do this in iOS. I find tutorials and start doing them and find they are deprecated or wrong. Can anyone help me figure out the basics of how to do it or at least a non-outdated tutorial of how I can do this? This app is for iOS 7 by the way. I need it to post the phone number to the php file I have and the PHP file returns status codes based on whether it was successful or not.

So this is what I have going so far without a third party library:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&phone=%@",@"phonenumberhere"];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url_here"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
```

Now if I check my SQL database I know it is working and it is correctly posting. However, How can I see the status code it returns?

Comment: the better way to ask is to post your objective-c attempt, otherwise this question looks like: "please translate my code for me".

Comment: Yes you are correct! I will post my attempt now. While waiting for an answer I got it to work to some degree. I will edit my post now to include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested in using a third party library (Although it generally simplify the work for you) something like this should work for you using native `NSURLConnection`.

```
- (void) postRequest
{
    NSString *postString = @"param1=val2&param2=val2";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataDelegate Methods
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    //Here handle the error
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //Here you get the meta data of the response
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //Here the actual data you can just add data to an
    //NSMutableData object each time this method is called
}
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //This is called when all the data is received
}
```

Comment: Yes! I found this here: http://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/ and it looks the same which is great because it worked. How would I check the return status code?

Comment: You can cast the response in `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` to `(NSHTTPURLResponse*)` and call `[response statusCode]`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I added this:

    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    int responseCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"%i", responseCode);

Answer (score 3):

I am using [AFNetworking library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for all http communicaton.

The code for post request will look like this:

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL]]; // BASE_URL is the web url prefix for example (http://example.com)

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"param1_value", @"param1_name", @"param2_value", @"param2_name", nil];

// URL_POST for example /post_page.php the end address will be http://example.com/post_page.php
[httpClient postPath:URL_POST parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Login response: %@",operation.responseString);
        //process success response

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //process http errors
}];
```

Comment: Ok so I added the AFNetworking library to a new group called AFNetworking. I am getting a "Use of undeclared identifier". Any idea?

Comment: Have you added #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h> to your source?

Comment: Oh thats what I forgot to do. Thank you for adding that comment. I have it working now without the library but as I am still learning app development I am sure I will use that in the near future!